# Bootstrap switch not working with data table responsive

Tags: datatable, responsive, bootstrap-switch

I am using Bootstrap switch for Laravel project. Bootstrap switch worked with Desktop data table. But not working with data table responsive. Please any help or suggestion is appreciated.